# FutureBuilder, SetState: Variable Not Updating When Deleting setState

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-futurebuilder

I learned that it's not good practice to have a setState(() AND a FutureBuilder together. When I delete my setState((), I noticed that the *isWaiting* variable no longer updates into the *MakeCards* class and stays at True. But when I leave in my setState, even if it's empty `setState((){     }` then isWaiting properly updates to False as it should. I need help with understanding why that is and how I can update *isWaiting* to False inside the *MakeCards* while deleting my setState(().

```
    bool isWaiting = true; <------------------------------------------
        
            Future<Map> getData() async {
                try {
                  List<String> coinData = await CoinData();
                  Map<String, List<String>> graphData = await GraphData()
                  
                  setState(() { <------------------------------------
                    coinValues = coinData;
                    graphValues = graphData;
                  });

                   isWaiting = false; <----------------------------------
            .
            . (some code)
            .
                return allDataValues;
              }
```

Build Method

```
                 MakeCards(
                    isWaiting: isWaiting, <-----------------------------
                    selectedCurrency: selectedCurrency,
                    coinData: allDataValues['lastCoinPrices'])
                .makeCards(),
    
                 FutureBuilder<Map>(
                      future: futureData,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        print("FutureBuilder started");
                        if (!snapshot.hasData)
                          return CircularProgressIndicator();
                        else if (snapshot.data.isEmpty)
                          return Container();
                        else {
                          print("FutureBuilder completed");
                          return Graph(snapshot.data);
                        }
                      })
```

MakeCards (separate file)

```
class MakeCards {
  MakeCards({this.isWaiting, this.selectedCurrency, this.coinData});

  bool isWaiting;
  String selectedCurrency;
  List<String> coinData = [];

  Row makeCards() {
    List<CryptoCard> cryptoCards = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < cryptoAbbreviation.length; i++) {
      cryptoCards.add(
        CryptoCard(
          cryptoCurrency: cryptoAbbreviation[i],
          selectedCurrency: selectedCurrency,
          value: isWaiting ? '---' : coinData[i], <-------------------------
          name: cryptoName[i],
          // iconContent: iconContent,
        ),
      );
    }

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: cryptoCards,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `setState` while you are using  `FutureBuilder`.

You may move the Future builder to the root of your widget tree (the part of the tree that depends on the data from that future)

Then replace the value passed through the variable `isWaiting` with the state of the snapshot.